# How to use knex object as type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function that accepts the knex instance as a parameter.

I try to do that by

```
import knex from "knex";
export async function createTestTable(_knex: ReturnType<knex>) {
    ... 
}
```

But it returns the `Cannot use namespace 'knex' as a type.ts(2709) error.` Is there any method I can do the correct type annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of knex there's a type that can be imported from the library

`Import { Knex } from 'knex'`

This can be used to correctly type the knex instance obj and additionally generics can be provided to it based on the db schema.

The equivalent of the type `Knex` would be `ReturnType<typeof knex>` so you can use it like that as well to type the instance.

sample usage:

```
import knex, { Knex } from 'knex';

const knexObj = knex({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: './data.db',
  },
});

async function connDB(kInstance: Knex) {
  await kInstance.schema
    .createTable('users', (table) => {
      table.increments('id');
      table.string('user_name');
    })
    // ...and another
    .createTable('accounts', (table) => {
      table.increments('id');
      table.string('account_name');
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('users.id');
    });
}

connDB(knexObj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeof` to get the type of `knex`, the value. It's currently being confused for the namespace.

```
import knex from "knex";

export async function createTestTable(_knex: ReturnType<typeof knex>) {
    
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0nGnw)